# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connection

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jdbc, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am new to Spring boot, and I tried to make a simple application using it. I have a mysql database, an entity, a repository and a controller. The problem is that when I try to run the app, I get the following error: "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connection".
This is application.properties:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8l3C.png)

Update: This is the class from the model:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

import lombok.Getter;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Getter
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Getter
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Getter
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Getter
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Getter
    private String email;
}
```

This is my repo:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/sample")
    public String showForm() {
        return "sample";
    }

    @GetMapping("/sample2")
    public String showForm2() {
        return "sample2";
    }
}
```

and the finally:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.example.spring.repository")
@EntityScan("com.example.spring.model")
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ReqAppApplication {
    @Bean(name="entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReqAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share project structure and application property file ?

Comment: I also tried with a postgres database, but I get the same error

Comment: Why are disable Datasource in main spring boot app file ?

Comment: Without the disable, I get the following error: Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine suitable jdbc url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your data source in Spring with your database connection details. Host, Port, Username, Password.